# in javascript filter how can I get the index of the element

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var ary=[{name:12},{name:5},{name:8},{name:130},{name:44}];
var filtered = ary.filter(function(element,index){return element.name == 44;});
```

how can I get the index of the element

Comment: "*how can I get the index of the element*" ... **what element?**

Comment: I think you meant "the element I found with the filter function".

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in function which can do that. You need to manually iterate to find that out

```
var result = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i += 1) {
    if (ary[i].name === 44) {
        result = i;
        break;
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Since you have only simple name value pairs, I would rather convert that to an array for if there is going to be multiple `indexOf` lookups.

```
var tempArray = ary.map(function(item) { return item.name; });
tempArray.indexOf(44);
# 4
```

Comment: Yea this one confuses me; he seems to be explicitly interested in `.filter()`, which does pass the array index as the second parameter. *edit* oh wait I see. (also, `.reduce()`, though it's a little unusual).

Comment: Also ES 6 has a `.findIndex()` function that appears to be exactly what the OP is looking for :)

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood the subject.

Answer (score 1):

OK I think I see: you want the index where `name` is found. Don't use `.filter()`, use `.reduce()`:

```
var position = ary.reduce(function(r, v, i) {
  if (v.name == 44)
    r = i;
  return r;
}, -1);
```

*edit* — use `.reduceRight()` instead of `.reduce()` if the search criteria might be satisfied by more than one element and you'd prefer to get the first one instead of the last. Probably a simple loop would be more efficient in that case, or else the ES6 function `.findIndex()` (which is basically exactly what you want, but not generally available yet).

Comment: If there two `44`s, it would return the index of the last 44 :) But, I am not very sure what exactly OP wants...

Comment: @thefourtheye yes that's true. I guess I could change it to `.reduceRight()` :)

Comment: Also, I would do `return v.name === 44 ? i : r`. +1 though :)

Comment: @thefourtheye yes I was trying to make it simple here :)

Answer (score 0):

`.filter` accepts a callback function which will be passed the current value and the index and the actual array itself.

In your case `index` argument has the index value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [{ name: 'Test 1' }, { name: 'Test 2' }];

array.filter(function(item, key){
    console.log('Item value:', item);
    console.log('Key:', key);
});
```